# In salt states, we use "grains.host" to get the host details. How do we get the AWS EC2 availability zone name using salt grains?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jinja2, salt-stack

In salt states, we use "grains.host" to get the host details. How do we get the AWS EC2 availability zone name using salt grains?

To get the hostname I give the below:

```
{%- if 'aws-dev-01' in grains.host %}
{%- set device = '.....' %}
```

To get the EC2 AZ name, are the below lines correct?

```
{%- if 'us-east-1a' in grains.availability_zone %}
{%- set device = '.....' %}
```

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary that is not how it works. The `availability_zone` grain is populated dynamically from the EC2 metadata service.

Comment: @Alex yes, they are correct. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, but you need to set `metadata_server_grains: true` in the minion config first.
https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/grains/all/salt.grains.metadata.html

In addition, only IMDSv1 is currently supported.
https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/57514